# The longest sub-array that all the elements less or equal A[i]

Tags: arrays, algorithm, stack, time-complexity

I have an array `A[1,...,n]` of positive numbers, for example:

```
[1, 2, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4]
```

I need to build an array `S[1,...,n]` according to the definition:

```
S[i] = max {k|∀i−k <j≤i :A[j] ≤ A[i] and k ≤ i}
```

It means to find the longest sub-array `A[i − k,..,i]` that all of its elements are less or equal `A[i]` for each index in the array.

I need to write an algorithm that creates the array S in **O(n) using Stack**.

For example for the array  [1,2,4,3,5] i need to return the array [1,2,3,2,5]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store (current_maximum, size_of_sequence) in stack for each sequence of increasing numbers. On each iteration you should add value to sequence (optionally merging adjacent sequences if new value is bigger)

```
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

std::vector<int> leq_subarrays(const std::vector<int>& numbers) {
  if (numbers.empty()) {
    return std::vector<int>();
  }
  std::vector<int> answer(numbers.size());
  std::stack<std::pair<int, int>> s;
  s.push(std::make_pair(numbers[0], 1));
  answer[0] = 1;
  for (size_t i = 1; i < numbers.size(); ++i) {
    const auto& value = numbers[i];
    int count = 1;
    while (!s.empty() && s.top().first <= value) {
      count += s.top().second;
      s.pop();
    }
    s.push(std::make_pair(value, count));
    answer[i] = count;
  }
  return answer;
}
```

Link to Ideone: http://ideone.com/SlZorX

Comment: That is a nice solution !!

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't find the max length. For example: [1,2,4,3,5] supposed to return [1,2,3,2,5] but it returns [1,2,3,1,5]

Comment: I just don't know how to find the max length of A[i] if it's bigger. For example, [1,2,4,3], how can I find the max length of 3 using Stack? Thank you

Comment: Why should algorithm return [1,2,3,2,5]? 3 is less than 4 therefore maximum subarray ending on 3 has size of one.

Comment: Yes but [1,2] is a sub-array where all the elements are less or equal 3. Therefore, is the maximum subarray until we see 3 (not ending on 3), or maybe I didn't understand the question

Comment: Oh ok I didn't understand it right. Thank you very much!